# How to implement iterator for doubly linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list, iterator

I have a custom doubly-linked list class and I want to implement iterator for it so I can use functions like std::sort and the one provided below. What can be done about it?

For example, now I have the implementation but it's bad. The following string

```cpp
std::cout << list.end() - list.begin() << std::endl;
```

outputs

```
-179191768
```

where list is my list class with 10 elements in it.

The function​ I want to work:

```cpp
template <typename I, typename C>
void quickSort(I begin, I end, C cmp) {
    if (begin >= end) throw new exception_incorrectSelection;
    I i = begin, j = end;
    T pivot = *(i + (j - i) / 2);
    while (i <= j) {
        while (cmp(*i, pivot)) ++i;
        while (cmp(pivot, *j)) --j;
        if (i <= j) {
            std::iter_swap(i, j);
            ++i;
            --j;
        }
    }
    if (j > begin) quickSort(begin, j, cmp);
    if (i < end) quickSort(i, end, cmp);
}
```

It breaks on exeption check for the reason expressed earlier.

Comment: `std::sort()` requires random access iterators, which don't agree very well with linked lists. Why the standard `std::list` has its own sort method (which likely uses merge sort)

Comment: So it's better to use indexation on sorting algorithms with lists?

Comment: It's better to use an algorithm that uses forward or bidirectional element access, like merge sort.

Comment: Indexing on a linked list doesn't work well for the same reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterators come in various categories. For a doubly-linked list, you'd normally implement a bidirectional iterator. A bidirectional iterator won't support `std::sort`, but will support many (most?) other algorithms, such as `find`, `find_if`, `accumulate`, and so on.

You *could* write an iterator for a doubly-linked list that supported the RandomAccessIterator concept (e.g., supported `iterator + int` and `iterator - int`) but it's open to question whether you'd really want to--you normally expect a random access iterator to provide constant time addition and subtraction, but with a linked list, they'd be linear time instead. As such, even though you're supporting the concept in terms of the operations it's required to support, you're violating the requirements on complexity:

> The `RandomAccessIterator` concept adds support for **constant-time** advancement with +=, +, -=, and -, as well as the computation of distance in **constant time** with -. Random access iterators also support array notation via subscripting.

[emphasis added]

So, although you could make it work with `std::sort` if you wanted, it's *probably* not a great idea to do so.

That leaves two choices: go ahead and produce the same interface anyway, and live with the fact that the random-access operations will have linear complexity, or rewrite your algorithm to work with what bidirectional iterators can provide. That would look something like this:

```
template <typename I, typename C>
void quickSort(I begin, I end, C cmp) {
    if (begin >= end) throw new exception_incorrectSelection;
    I i = begin, j = end;
    T pivot = *(i + std::distance(i, j) / 2); // <--
    while (i <= j) {
        while (cmp(*i, pivot)) ++i;
        while (cmp(pivot, *j)) --j;
        if (i <= j) {
            std::iter_swap(i, j);
            ++i;
            --j;
        }
    }
    if (j > begin) quickSort(begin, j, cmp);
    if (i < end) quickSort(i, end, cmp);
}
```

At least as usually implemented, `std::distance` will do something like this:

```
template <class Iter>
size_t distance(Iter a, Iter b) { 
    size_t ret = 0;

    while (a != b) {
       ++a;
       ++ret;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

...so as long as your iterator supports `++` and `!=`, that'll normally be enough for it to work with `std::distance`.